# Exchange inherited permissions

Tags: permissions, exchange

We have situations where I would like to keep an AD account active for legal reasons for access to personal payroll data only. We would like to block access to everything else including the users own email yet keep the mailbox active.

Though there's a few things I could do manually to achieve this I would like to partially automate it. I've create an AD group with the intent of adding users to this with certain deny permissions within Exchange and AD. AD is OK as I have GPO's which 'Deny logon' to members of the group.

For Exchange I have run the following:

```
Get-MailboxDatabase -Identity "DB01" | Add-ADPermission -User "DOMAIN\DenyGroup" -AccessRights ExtendedRight -ExtendedRights Receive-As -Deny
```

The outcome of this for the particular user is:

```
Get-MailboxPermission BadUser

User                   AccessRights                                    IsInherited Deny
----                   ------------                                    ----------- ----
NT AUTHORITY\SELF      {FullAccess, ReadPermission}                    False       False
DOMAIN\Administrator   {FullAccess}                                    True        True
DOMAIN\Domain Admins   {FullAccess}                                    True        True
DOMAIN\Enterprise A... {FullAccess}                                    True        True
DOMAIN\Organization... {FullAccess}                                    True        True
DOMAIN\DenyGroup       {FullAccess}                                    True        True
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM    {FullAccess}                                    True        False
NT AUTHORITY\NETW...   {ReadPermission}                                True        False
```

As can be seen, the DenyGroup (which the user is a member of) is denied FullAccess to the mailbox yet the user can still access email via OWA. I know that the NT AUTHORITY\SELF {FullAccess, ReadPermission} still exists but I was hoping to have it working where I don't have to fiddle with this and the deny would take precedence.

Is there some form of precedence in regards to inherited permissions and permissions applied at the local object level? I would have thought an explicit Deny would override anything.

Comment: Have you considered changing the user's "logon hours" to nothing, or expiring the password (or the whole account)?

Comment: Your Exchange command denies Receive-As, not FullAccess. You could disconnect the Mailbox (it will be kept for a time depending on your configuration).

Comment: Thanks but neither suit. Logon hours needs to be 'always' so they can get to payroll. Disconnect won't work as the mailbox needs to be active for others to read incoming and respond. I don't believe that Add-ADPermission has an AccessRight of FullAccess but Receive-As shows as FullAccess when a Get-MailboxPermission is run.